# PHP/MySQL Date Search

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My script works fine for all sales but skips all sales on the 15th.

The MySQL rows for the period look like this:
ID: 10 START: 2010-12-01 END: 2010-12-15

The MySQL rows for the sales look like this:
DATE: 2010-12-15 20:40:26

```
$period_info=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT start,end FROM period WHERE id='$period' LIMIT 1"));
$start=$period_info["start"];
$end=$period_info["end"];

$total_sales=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE seller='$seller' AND date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'"));
```

And ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because MySQL uses 00:00:00 as the time for the DATE type. I think you can use:

`"SELECT * FROM sales WHERE seller='$seller' AND (CAST date AS DATE) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'"`.

Answer (score 1):

Only compare the date part of the datetime, and ignore the time part:

```
WHERE DATE(`date`) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
```

Comment: Awesome! I can stop pulling out my hair now. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For best results when using [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE.